# How to measure the time an application takes to start up in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, performance-testing

I have an GUI application that takes a while to load all its plugins, before it is ready to be used by the user.

I want to write a C# program that would measure the time taken for this application to start up. I thought the Process.WaitForInputIdle() method would do the trick, but it doesn't. It exits as soon as the process is started.

What I have now is this:

```
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;

Process myAppUnderTest = Process.Start("C:\\Program Files\\My App\app_under_test.ext");

myAppUnderTest.WaitForInputIdle();   //Wait until the application is idle.

DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;

int elapsedTimeInSecs = endTime.Subtract(startTime).Seconds;

Console.WriteLine("Start up time (sec): {0}", elapsedTimeInSecs);
```

How can I get the start up time that I intend?

Comment: For start you can use StopWatch class, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx instead of DateTime. As for the start time, are you allowed to change the code of the test application ?

Comment: No. I cannot change the code of the application that I want to test. But if I could, what are you suggesting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I say it's very difficult.

How do you classify an application loaded and ready? If there is a way (which I don't think so) then it would be easy.

But if the app you are loading signals you in certain way (IPC/files/network), then you can capture that signal and say the app is loaded. In that case, you can use a timer/stopwatch/performance counter.

If you can modify the to be timed app, then you can achieve in various ways. If its external to you, I doubt there is any easy way.

Comment: The to be timed app is external.

Comment: Then you might need to study if there is any way this external app can signal you when it is ready/loaded. Are you sure you really want this external dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Process.WaitForInputIdle() respones to the main window.  Once that process starts up it will move on.  Is there a message on the main the main window you can look at that indicates the app is in a ready state? If so you can try putting or app in a loop unitl that is present or so much time has passed.  As has been noted you will probably also want to look at the  Stopwatch class for your timing.

Just a couple of other thoughts as you are doing this.  Make sure that this process is the only one running.  You can sometimes get some conflicts otherwise.  You may need to play arround with figuring out what the trigger is to tell you when the app is fully loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `StopWatch` or something, then examine the time consumed like

```
        var app = builder.Build();
        app.Lifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(() =>
        {
            logger.LogCritical("" + stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
        });
```

Comment: The answer isn't applicable to the question, because the question was refereing to an external application where it isn't possible to add those lines of code.